Confusion about the criteria for a complete metric space to be a length space
According to corollary 2.4.17 from the textbook "A Course In Metric Geometry" we have
A complete metric space $(X, d)$ is a length space iff,
given a positive $\varepsilon$ and two points $x, y \in X$, there exists a finite sequence
of points $x = x_1, x_2,..., x_k = y$ such that every two neighboring points in
this sequence are $\varepsilon$-close (i.e., $d(x_i, x_{i+1}) \leq \varepsilon$ for all $i = 1,..., k − 1)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} d(x_i, x_{i+1}) < d(x, y) + \varepsilon$.
However, I do not believe this claim to be correct. For example, the points $-1$ and $1$ as a sub metric space of $\mathbb{R}$. If we give this the induced Length Structure, then $d_L(1,-1) = \infty$ (because there are no continuous paths between $1$ and $-1$). This is also clearly a complete metric space because every Cauchy Sequence converges. However, there is no finite set of points between $1$ and $-1$ that is $\varepsilon$-close for any $\varepsilon > 0$. Is this a contradiction to the corollary? Do they mean to say a Complete, bounded metric space?

Here, as in many other places, they implicitly assume that the metric takes only finite values. Sigh...

@MoisheKohan Indeed, the book has many errors. It is a great book though; I have wished for some time that they would publish a new edition...

Agree..........

They have a webpage with errata for the book here.
In the errata they say the following regarding sections 2.4-2.5:

"Although we usually allow infinite distances, many statements here are obviously valid for finite metrics only. This condition has to be added where necessary."

Thus, in Corollary 2.4.17 infinite distances are actually not allowed. I found that the finiteness of distances is implicitly assumed in other places in the book, not just in sections 2.4-2.5.
